# Python/Pygame - Sprite fails to blit

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

My player sprite fails to blit. However, when I uncomment the Rectangle code and comment the sprite code, it blits perfectly fine.

I do not receive an error message when loading the image, the sprite simply does not show up. The controls also act a bit wonky, with it seeming to "float" in the air unless it collides with a wall and jumping not functioning right. I know that it can find the image because a direct `blit` works.

Whenever I uncomment the Rect code and comment the load_image() code the controls function perfectly.

[Here is an image of the screen with load_image().](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Xxx.png)

[Here is an image of the screen without load_image().](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGaep.png)

I have tried directly bilting the image instead of using the `for e in entities` loop with specified coordinates. It worked, however as specific `x` and `y` values were used, the image obviously stayed in the same place, therefore staying at the coordinates on the screen instead of displaying the player's movements. Whenever I run `screen.blit(player.image, camera.apply(player))` it does not show up at all.

I have omitted certain things in the code (level array, other classes, etc) but I believe that the necessities are here. If this has a very simple fix, well, I'll feel pretty dumb :/

```
class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):

  def __init__(self, x, y):
    Entity.__init__(self)
    self.xlevel = 0
    self.ylevel = 0
    self.onGround = False
   # self.image = Surface((32, 32))
   # self.image.fill(Color("#000000"))
   # self.image.convert()
   # self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)
    self.image, self.rect = load_image("zur.png", colorkey=((255, 255, 255)))


class Camera(object):
  def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
    self.camera_func = camera_func
    self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

  def apply(self, target):
    return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

  def update(self, target):
    self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
  l, t, _, _ = target_rect
  _, _, w, h = camera
  return Rect(-l + HALF_WIDTH, -t + HALF_HEIGHT, w, h)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
  l, t, _, _ = target_rect
  _, _, w, h = camera
  l, t, _, _ = -l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h # center player

  l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling at the left edge
  l = max(-(camera.width-WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling at the right edge
  t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling at the bottom
  t = min(0, t)                           # stop scrolling at the top

  return Rect(l, t, w, h)

def load_image(name, colorkey=None):
  fullname = os.path.join('assets', name)
  try:
    image = pygame.image.load(fullname)
  except pygame.error, message:
    print 'Cannot load image ' + name + ". Exiting."
    raise SystemExit, message
  image = image.convert()
  if colorkey is not None:
    if colorkey is -1:
      colorkey = image.get_at((0, 0))
    image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
  return image, image.get_rect()

def main():
  global cameraX, cameraY
  global mouseX, mouseY
  global bulletExists
  mouseX = 0
  mouseY = 0
  bulletExists = False
  pygame.init()

  screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)  
  pygame.display.set_caption("Tale of Zur")
  clock = pygame.time.Clock()

  up = down = left = right = running = False
  x = y = 0

  background_images = []
  platforms = []

  background_images.append(pygame.image.load("assets/starting_background_1.jpg").convert())

  entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
  player = Player(32, 32)
  bulletx = int(player.xlevel)
  bullety = int(player.ylevel)



    bullet = Bullet(player.rect.left, player.rect.top)
    bullet.update(player.rect.left, player.rect.top)
    screen.blit(background_images[0], [0, 0])


    if bulletExists is True:
      for i in range(10):
        if up and i is not 10:
          screen.blit(bullet.image, [bullet.bulletxpos + i, player.rect.top])  
        else:
          screen.blit(bullet.image, [bullet.bulletxpos - i, player.rect.top])


    camera.update(player)
    player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)

    for e in entities:
      screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You don't appear to have added the sprites to the entities group, hence it is empty.

Comment: I omitted the while loop of the program and the piece of code that showed me adding the player to the entitites list. However, there is a piece that says `entities.add(player)`, so that is not the problem.

Comment: This is not a runnable piece of code, so it is hard to test it.

Comment: Apologies. [Here](http://hastebin.com/igazipeqoq.py) it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this (in the Camera.apply() method):

```
r = target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)
print r
```

the y co-ordinate is at -25, so it is blitting the image off-screen.  I am not sure why this is, but this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try my best to figure this out.